# R check for duplicates then divide one column with another

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe.

```
    1     2     3 
A   1    100   45
B   1    100   30
C   2    80    20
```

First off I want to find the duplicate elements in the rows (for A and B, 1 = 1). After that I want R to add up A3 and B3 (45 + 30 = 75), but only if 1 is a duplicate. Then, divide A3 with that answer (so, 45 / 75 = 0.6), the same for B3 and the answer. And then multiply that with A2 and A3 respectively.

These answers should update the dataframe accordingly. So A2 should become 60 and B2 should become 40.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(
'A   1    100   45
B   1    100   30
C   2    80    20'), header = FALSE)

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

dt[,NewV4 := V3*V4/sum(V4), by = 'V2']
```

Output -

```
> dt
   V1 V2  V3 V4 NewV4
1:  A  1 100 45    60
2:  B  1 100 30    40
3:  C  2  80 20    80
```

Comment: How should I interpret the copy paste of the dataframe in the R function? I tried df <- read.table(textConnection(data), header = FALSE) but this gives me invalid 'text' argument.

Comment: I think Codoremifa just made a "toy" data set for illustration purpose. You can use your own dataframe, name it as `df` then continue with the code starting from `library(data.table)`.